# Reading a large file, starting from a byte position and writing it to a new file, vb.net

Tags: vb.net, filestream

I have this code to read large files and write them  in bytes using buffer , I want to read a specific size. for example, I have a file of size 100 kb. I want to read the last 30kb only and save them into a new file.
I also don't fully understand how this reader work, but I want to use it so it cannot load all the file in memory.

```
 Sub readthis(filein As String, fileout As Of String, startingposition as integer)
        Dim bytesRead As Integer
        Dim buffer(4096) As Byte
        Using inFile As New IO.FileStream(filein, FileMode.Open)
            Using outFile As New IO.FileStream(fileout, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)
                Do
                    bytesRead = inFile.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                    If bytesRead > 0 Then
                        outFile.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                    End If
                Loop While bytesRead > 0
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Comment: `inFile.Seek(startingposition, SeekOrigin.Begin)`. Where's `fileout.Item(i)` coming from? That's a file name, pass just `fileout`. Why are you using `FileMode.Append`?

Comment: yea, sorry.i edited it. so where can i use `inFile.Seek(startingposition, SeekOrigin.Begin)`

Comment: Before you start reading from that Stream.

Comment: ok, it works, but i need this to work on the same exe. supposethat the `filein` is this app itself, it doesn't work because the app is already opend. how can i overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    readthis("d:\log\tmp1.txt", "d:\log\tmp2.txt", 30)

End Sub

Sub readthis(filein As String, fileout As String, numlastbytes As Integer)

    Dim fs As New IO.FileStream(filein, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    fs.Seek(-numlastbytes, SeekOrigin.End)
    Dim bytearray(numlastbytes) As Byte
    Dim numbytesread As Integer = fs.Read(bytearray, 0, numlastbytes)
    fs.Close()
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(fileout, bytearray, False)

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, because you asked "I want to read the last 30kb"